# Server crashed, I restarted, and now Devise is broken?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm working on a closed blog and discussion network-esque app, and everything's been fine; Devise, cancan, logins, everything was working properly. When I was tweaking around with implementing a user/relationships model for following other users, the server crashed. Here's what came out the console that was running the server. Hopefully it doesn't show how messy of a coder I am. I don't know how much of this paste is relevant, but the actual crash is at the very bottom.

```
Started GET "/user/dyylannnn" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Aug 01 12:12:48 -0400 2012

SQLite3::ConstraintException (columns follower_id, followed_id are not unique):
  activerecord (3.2.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:69:in `close'
  activerecord (3.2.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:69:in `dealloc'
  activerecord (3.2.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:58:in `clear'
  activerecord (3.2.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:57:in `each'
  activerecord (3.2.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:57:in `clear'
  activerecord (3.2.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:144:in `clear_cache!'
  activerecord (3.2.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:138:in `disconnect!'
  activerecord (3.2.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:151:in `clear_reloadable_connections!'
  activerecord (3.2.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:149:in `each'
  activerecord (3.2.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:149:in `clear_reloadable_connections!'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
  activerecord (3.2.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:147:in `clear_reloadable_connections!'
  activerecord (3.2.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:386:in `clear_reloadable_connections!'
  activerecord (3.2.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:386:in `each_value'
  activerecord (3.2.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:386:in `clear_reloadable_connections!'
  activerecord (3.2.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:186:in `__send__'
  activerecord (3.2.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:186:in `clear_reloadable_connections!'
  activerecord (3.2.7) lib/active_record/railtie.rb:96:in `_callback_before_3'
  activesupport (3.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run__2144987145__prepare__4__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `send'
  activesupport (3.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `send'
  activesupport (3.2.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
  actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.7) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.7) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.7) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
  railties (3.2.7) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
  railties (3.2.7) lib/rails/commands.rb:55
  railties (3.2.7) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
  railties (3.2.7) lib/rails/commands.rb:50
  script/rails:6:in `require'
  script/rails:6


  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (13.5ms)
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:69: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]

Abort trap
```

So I was like "Huh, that's odd," and restarted the server, but everything is broken now. The perpetrator seems to be Devise. If it's not that 'current_user isn't an undefined local variable or method', it's that the Devise implementation in my navbar (bootstrap ftw) is also broken. Whatever the error, though, every page on my site is broken and it all seems to be devise related.

I'm doing this project to familiarize myself with Rails and I do like it a lot, but I'm still new to this and I have no idea wtf just happened. Help? I can paste any other code you guys might request.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but this line: `SQLite3::ConstraintException (columns follower_id, followed_id are not unique):` would lead me to believe that your SQLight database may be corrupted (possibly due to the hard crash?).

Comment: that sounds plausible. I'll try resetting from my schema, will let you know what happens. thanks!

Comment: Have you tried dropping and recreating the database? I agree its probably an issue with SQLite db

Comment: so i ran this "rake db:drop db:create db:migrate" and even restarted the server again. Still the same problem :\

Answer (score 0):

if its your dev machine try recreating the database

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
```

Comment: ran "rake db:drop db:create db:migrate", no fix :\

Answer (score 0):

You could have a corrupted gem. Try

```
bundle exec gem uninstall <devise gem name>
```

for whatever version of Devise you are using. And then run `bundle install` again. This should uninstall and reinstall the Devise gem.

If that doesn't work, you could try the brute force approach of cloning your repository to a new directory.

Comment: done. and restarted the server. still to no avail. can you explain this brute force approach?

Comment: The brute force approach assumes you have a git repository. If you do not, you can cobble together something similar. When you clone a repo, you get the raw source code, but you have to reinitialize everything from scratch. That is, do `bundle install`, `rake db:create db:migrate` all over again. It is like starting again from scratch.

Comment: okay, thanks for advising. I'll put all that together and let you know how it goes

Comment: didn't work. as I've worked on my project, I've copied the app's folders periodically using Mac's duplicate button so i had backups. my latest backup is pretty far back, but i tried it in desperation just now. IT doesn't work. in light of that, could I have corrupted my rails installation perhaps and not the individual app?

Comment: Are you using RVM? If yes, then you can create a new gemset and use it instead. That might give you a fresh set of gems (I think, I am now well outside my sphere of knowledge).